# Android start horizontal progress bar from center

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I'm working on a custom Android widget that will both positive and negative values as a bar. Since I'm going with a stock look, I thought I'd extend the `ProgressBar` class and use that as a base for my widget. However, I can't seem to find a way to programatically get a handle on the bar itself (as opposed to the entire drawable or the entire canvas) so that I can set the start of the `Rect` to the middle of the bar.

The effect I'd like to achieve is something like this (showing a negative value, if it were positive obviously it would be going the other way).

[image: two way progress bar]

I've already overridden the progress setters to check if we've stored a negative value:

```
private boolean isNegative;

@Override
public void setProgress(final int progress) {
    isNegative = progress < 0;
    super.setProgress(Math.min(Math.abs(progress), this.getMax()));
}

@Override
public int getProgress() {
    return (isNegative ? -1 : 1) * super.getProgress();
}
```

It's really just drawing the thing that I can't figure out. This only needs to target the latest API (19 as of this post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's too late to answer, but you could use two `ProgressBar`, set the first to be right to left with `progressBar.setRotation(180);` and then treat them independently, updating both when your status changes.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but sometimes simple hacks aren't such a bad thing. Silly though it sounds, I didn't even think to do it this way (and went with a completely custom job). Thanks.